# How do I center an svg in my html?

Tags: html, xml, svg

Note that I am not using CSS here. I want to know how to center an svg in my html code (inline XML).

Here is the code (I got the icon from free iconfinder.com):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><!DOCTYPE svg  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN''http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'>
<svg enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100px" height="100px"><path d="M488.8,230.3h-7.2C471.4,140,408,65.6,323.6,39.2c-6.8-11.2-11.4-17.4-11.7-17.7c-13.9-17-31.3-8.9-37.2,8.2  c-6.1-0.5-12.3-0.8-18.6-0.8s-12.5,0.3-18.6,0.8c-5.9-17.1-23.3-25.2-37.2-8.2c-0.3,0.4-4.9,6.5-11.7,17.7  C104,65.6,40.6,140,30.4,230.3h-7.2c-12.7,0-23.1,10.4-23.1,23.1v5.1c0,12.7,10.4,23.1,23.1,23.1h7.2  c10.2,90.5,73.8,165,158.5,191.2c3.4,5.9,6.9,11.8,10.6,17.7c12.8,17,32.8,8.4,39.7-8.2c5.5,0.4,11.1,0.6,16.8,0.6  s11.2-0.2,16.8-0.6c6.9,16.6,27,25.2,39.7,8.2c3.7-5.9,7.2-11.8,10.6-17.7c84.6-26.2,148.2-100.8,158.5-191.2h7.2  c12.7,0,23.1-10.4,23.1-23.1v-5.1C511.9,240.7,501.5,230.3,488.8,230.3z M436.3,230.3h-53.2c-3.1-49.9-15-93.2-28.2-127.2  C398.1,131.2,428.8,177.1,436.3,230.3z M286.5,76.5c15.1,24.2,44,79.4,49.1,153.9H176.3c5.1-74.5,34-129.7,49.1-153.9  c9.9-1.7,20.1-2.6,30.5-2.6S276.6,74.8,286.5,76.5z M157.2,103.1c-13.2,34-25.2,77.3-28.2,127.2H75.7  C83.2,177.1,113.9,131.2,157.2,103.1z M75.7,281.7H129c2.6,39.8,11.3,82.8,29.2,127.9C114.4,381.6,83.3,335.3,75.7,281.7z   M226.4,435.7c-31.4-55.3-45.6-107.4-49.6-154h158.5c-4,46.7-18.2,98.7-49.6,154c-9.6,1.6-19.5,2.4-29.6,2.4S236,437.3,226.4,435.7z   M353.8,409.6c17.9-45.1,26.6-88.1,29.2-127.9h53.3C428.7,335.3,397.6,381.6,353.8,409.6z" fill="#303A3F"/>
</svg>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to center vertically, horizontally or both?

Comment: I'm trying to center it on the page, so both vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very outdated and I would highly recommend simply using CSS, but one option is to use a table:

```
<table height="100%" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr> 
        <td valign="middle" align="center"> 
            <svg></svg> 
        </td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```

You could also maybe use the `<center>` tag, but again that is very outdated.

**UPDATE:**

I've just seen your comment above, and so to also vertically align the icon add `height="100%"` to the `<table>` element and add `valign="middle"` to the `<td>` element, as it appears updated above.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to use CSS too, but the site I'm using this on doesn't have it (rather antiquated framework). I will try this out, thanks!

Comment: And I already tried using the <center> tag, and it didn't work.

Comment: @user5323210 ah that makes sense.. I've updated to include vertical alignment as well - hope this helps.

Comment: @user5323210 on a side note I've just tried it with the `<center>` tag and it worked fine for me - maybe it's a browser thing! Incidentally there is no equivalent bespoke vertical-alignment tag so this wouldn't have helped you anyway

Comment: So I tried it and it worked (almost) perfectly! Now the only problem is: there is a faint line at the bottom of my icon. Any ideas how to get rid of that?

Comment: Great! Hmm, could you possibly send an image of the output? And also show me the exact mark-up you're using? Plus what browser are you using, as it's working fine for me in Chrome, Firefox and IE11? Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: Sorry I would move this to chat but it looks like I'm a new user on Stack Overflow so I can't do that yet. I'm using Safari on a Mac, and (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2gWS96jmBoqbGp0SWZpZnFUZkE/view) is a link to an image of what it looks like.

Comment: Not a problem! Tell me, can you still see the same effect here: http://scratchpad.io/grubby-worm-7158

Comment: Nope, that looks perfect! What did you change exactly?

Comment: Would you mind just trying the code pasted on there in your actual file then? In case there's any slight differences.. If not then it may be a browser issue but I'm looking at it now using Safari on my iPad and there are no lines!

Comment: Also did you use a different icon for the image you sent me? Odd that they're not the same

Comment: Ah yes I accidentally sent the code to the other icon I was trying to do the same thing with. I'm plugging this in now and waiting for the website to refresh... If this doesn't work, I'm probably just going to chalk it up to slight interface/browser differences. The hard part was getting it centered, so thank you for that!!

Comment: @RW123 Oh right I see, well I hope it works and yes like I said: Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari all working fine for me so if there is still an issue I'd be stumped! Glad I could help though